# Update one JSON file values with values from another JSON using JQ

Tags: json, merge, updates, jq

So I have two JSON files:

`bosh.json:`

```
{
  "key_pair_name": "my-aws-keypair",
  "ssh_private_key": "my-key-name",
  "trusted_certificates": "my-trusted-certs"
}
```

`model.json:`

```
{
  "trusted_certificates": "vault-supplied-value",
  "vm_password_type": "generate"
}
```

and I want to update the model.json file with the bosh.json file so it looks like this:

```
{
  "trusted_certificates": "my-trusted-certs",
  "vm_password_type": "generate"
}
```

I tried this:

```
jq --argfile bosh bosh.json '. += $bosh' model.json
```

but I get too many keys

```
{
  "trusted_certificates": "my-trusted-certs",
  "vm_password_type": "generate",
  "key_pair_name": "my-aws-keypair",
  "ssh_private_key": "my-key-name"
}
```

and

```
jq --argfile bosh bosh.json '. + $bosh' model.json
```

yeilds the same...

```
{
  "trusted_certificates": "my-trusted-certs",
  "vm_password_type": "generate",
  "key_pair_name": "my-aws-keypair",
  "ssh_private_key": "my-key-name"
}
```

while this

```
jq --argfile bosh bosh.json '. = $bosh' model.json
```

yields the incorrect keys...

```
{
  "key_pair_name": "my-aws-keypair",
  "ssh_private_key": "my-key-name",
  "trusted_certificates": "my-trusted-certs"
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to get the expected results using jq?
by the way, I cannot use the value of the key for the updates, as i will have unexpected results in other permutations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements are not completely clear, but here's the solution to one interpretation.  This solution can easily be modified to match the other obvious interpretation.

Assuming the file bosh.jq contains the following jq program:

```
reduce keys[] as $k (.; if $bosh|has($k) then .[$k] = $bosh[$k] else . end)
```

then the command:

```
jq --argfile bosh bosh.json -f bosh.jq model.json
```

will in effect emit the edited version of model.json.

### Using with_entries

If you prefer a reduce-free approach, consider:

```
with_entries(.key as $k | if $bosh|has($k) then .value = $bosh[$k] else . end )
```

Note that `if $bosh|has($k) ...` is NOT the same as `if $bosh[$k] ...`.

Comment: Thanks @peak.  Both of these solutions will work well.

Comment: What should be modified in case of input(both JSON) is array?

Answer (score 1):

***jq*** solution:

```
jq --argfile bosh bosh.json 'with_entries( 
         if $bosh[.key] then .value = $bosh[.key] else . end)' model.json
```

The output:

```
{
  "trusted_certificates": "my-trusted-certs",
  "vm_password_type": "generate"
}
```

---

- `if $bosh[.key] then .value = $bosh[.key] else . end` - update *model*'s value only for matched keys

Comment: @RomanPerekgrest - that should have been: with_entries( .key as $k | if $bosh|has($k) then .value = $bosh[$k] else . end )