# Update one JSON file values with values from another JSON using JQ (on all levels)

Tags: json, merge, jq

I have two JSON files:

> source.json:

```
{
  "general": {
    "level1": {
      "key1": "x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x",
      "key3": "z-z-z-z-z-z-z-z",
      "key4": "w-w-w-w-w-w-w-w"
    },
    "another" : {
      "key": "123456",
      "comments": {
        "one": "111",
        "other": "222"
      }
    }
  },
  "title": "The best"
}
```

and the

> target.json:

```
{
  "general": {
    "level1": {
      "key1": "xxxxxxxx",
      "key2": "yyyyyyyy",
      "key3": "zzzzzzzz"
    },
    "onemore": {
      "kkeeyy": "0000000"
    }
  },
  "specific": {
    "stuff": "test"
  },
  "title": {
    "one": "one title",
    "other": "other title"
  }
}
```

I need all the values for keys which exist in both files, copied from *source.json* to *target.json*, considering all the levels.
I've seen and tested the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855206/update-one-json-file-values-with-values-from-another-json-using-jq).
It only copies the first level of keys, and I couldn't get it to do what I need.
The result from solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855206/update-one-json-file-values-with-values-from-another-json-using-jq), looks like this:

```
{
  "general": {
    "level1": {
      "key1": "x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x",
      "key3": "z-z-z-z-z-z-z-z",
      "key4": "w-w-w-w-w-w-w-w"
    },
    "another": {
      "key": "123456",
      "comments": {
        "one": "111",
        "other": "222"
      }
    }
  },
  "specific": {
    "stuff": "test"
  },
  "title": "The best"
}
```

Everything under the "general" key was copied as is.
What I need, is this:

```
{
  "general": {
    "level1": {
      "key1": "x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x",
      "key2": "yyyyyyyy",
      "key3": "z-z-z-z-z-z-z-z"
    },
    "onemore": {
      "kkeeyy": "0000000"
    }
  },
  "specific": {
    "stuff": "test"
  },
  "title": {
    "one": "one title",
    "other": "other title"
  }
}
```

Only "key1" and "key3" should be copied.
Keys in *target JSON* must not be deleted and new keys should not be created.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Good that you have shown your research and attempt to solve the problem. But you should include the actual code you have tried to solve your problem. Linking to another Q is OK for context, but Qs should be self contained. Good luck.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following provides a solution to the revised question, which is actually about "paths" rather than "keys".

```
([$target|paths(scalars)] | unique) as $paths
| reduce ($source|paths(scalars)) as $p
    ($target;
     if $paths | bsearch($p) > -1 
     then setpath($p; $source|getpath($p))
     else . end)
```

`unique` is called so that binary search can be used subsequently.

### Invocation:

```
jq -n --argfile source source.json --argfile target target.json -f program.jq
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach you could take is get all the paths to all scalar values for each input and take the set intersections. Then copy values from source to target from those paths.

First we'll need an intersect function (which was surprisingly difficult to craft):

```
def set_intersect($other):
    (map({ ($other[] | tojson): true }) | add) as $o
    | reduce (.[] | tojson) as $v ({}; if $o[$v] then .[$v] = true else . end)
    | keys_unsorted
    | map(fromjson);
```

Then to do the update:

```
$ jq --argfile s source.json '
reduce ([paths(scalars)] | set_intersect([$s | paths(scalars)])[]) as $p (.;
    setpath($p; $s | getpath($p))
)
' target.json
```

Answer (score 1):

[Note: this response answers the original question, with respect to the original data. The OP may have had paths in mind rather than keys.]

There is no need to compute the intersection to achieve a reasonably efficient solution.

First, let's hypothesize the following invocation of jq:

```
jq -n --argfile source source.json --argfile target target.json -f copy.jq
```

In the file copy.jq, we can begin by defining a helper function:

```
# emit an array of the distinct terminal keys in the input entity
def keys: [paths | .[-1] | select(type=="string")] | unique;
```

In order to inspect all the paths to leaf elements of `$source`, we can use `tostream`:

```
($target | keys) as $t
| reduce ($source|tostream|select(length==2)) as [$p,$v]
    ($target;
     if $t|index($p[-1]) then setpath($p; $v) else . end)
```

### Alternatives

Since $t is sorted, it would (at least in theory) make sense to use `bsearch` instead of `index`:

```
 bsearch($p[-1]) > -1
```

Also, instead of `tostream` we could use `paths(scalars)`.

Putting these alternatives together:

```
($target | keys) as $t
| reduce ($source|paths(scalars)) as $p
    ($target;
     if $t|bsearch($p[-1]) > -1 
     then setpath($p; $source|getpath($p))
     else . end)
```

### Output

```
{
  "general": {
    "level1": {
      "key1": "x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x",
      "key2": "yyyyyyyy",
      "key3": "z-z-z-z-z-z-z-z"
    },
    "onemore": {
      "kkeeyy": "0000000"
    }
  },
  "specific": {
    "stuff": "test"
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question with better JSON examples, to include cases which were not working well with this solution, leading to deleted keys or new keys being added to the target file

Comment: Your update suggests your requirements should refer to paths rather than keys. Please clarify.